# PHP and Regex: how can I split a string with unicode words (including abreviations with ')?

Tags: php, regex-negation, preg-split

**Hello, I need a array with all the words from a Text, ignoring the signs !&,. and everything that the {L} already do - except ' because it is used by some words like "can't". This is what I came so far:**

```
 $Text = "This is a Text! I can't understand any of these 11 words, by the way.";

    $criteria="(\P{L}+|')";
    $Text= preg_split($criteria, $Text);
```

**Output**
Array: ['This','is','a','Text','I',**'can','t'**,'understand','any','of','these','words','by','the','way']

the point is that I want to consider **can't** as a word not to be split. How can I put this ' exception on it? Thanks in advance for your time and patience!**

Comment: Please format your question so that it is readable.

Answer (score 2):

may be you are looking for this.

```
 <?php
$Text = "This is a Text! I can't understand any of these 11 words, by the way.";

    $criteria="/[\s.!,]+/";
    $Text= preg_split($criteria, $Text);
print_r($Text);
?>
```

Just put the symbol that you want to be ignored in big brackets.
Here \s is for space and tabs to ignore

**Output**
Array ( [0] => This [1] => is [2] => a [3] => Text [4] => I [5] => can't [6] => understand [7] => any [8] => of [9] => these [10] => 11 [11] => words [12] => by [13] => the [14] => way [15] => )

Comment: hi, thanks. But in fact I need to escape also the !., and all the signs that the {L} from preg_split already does. I need a array with the words of the sentence :)

Comment: @CristianLotharRöthig see carefully the regex "/[\s.!,]+/"; i used !, and . to escape ...try to run the code

Comment: thanks! it worked like a charm! It is unicode compliant?